# How to take More Control of Outbound Messages in twilio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am using node js api for twilio to send outbound messages. I have a cron job going in google cloud which runs in each one minute. I am using a firestore function which triggered by the a pubsub topic. I send sms inside the firestore function.

I want to figure out how to control over the messages. I faced the issue and more than 10000 messages has been queued in twilio.

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
client.messages.create({
       from: msgFromNum,
       to: uNA.mobile_num,
       body: uNA.message
 })
.then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the messages are queued you can not stop sending it in Twilio. But you can set the **validityPeriod** for outbound messages. Also put some conditions before sending the message. As you have mentioned you are running cron job in 1mins. So Don't overload the messages in each minute.

> The message can remain in outgoing queue for a maximum of 15 seconds after that it will be removed from queued messages.

```
async sendSms() { 
   const accountSid = 'AC****************************';
   const authToken = '8b*****************************';
   const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
   const msgFromNum = '+1*********';
   const message = await client.messages.create({
      from: msgFromNum,
      to: '+1*********',
      body: 'The message can remain in our outgoing queue for maximum 15 seconds.',
    validityPeriod: 15 // in seconds
   })
   console.log(message.sid);
}
```